# How to add html element inside binding in nuxt or vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

As the title state, I want to try adding a html element `<br />` inside a data bind, but i can't do it right, I'm quite confused of how to do it right

let say I have this text `I like to playing games` and I want to add `<br />` like this `I like playing <br /> games`, it sound simple right? but I can't do this right inside data-bind.

this is my code:

```
<aqua-text
 class="text-position"
 :b-section-title="'I like to playing' + <br /> + 'games'"
 :description="
 'Game is fun after all'
 "
/>
```

this is what `<aqua-text>` looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ bSectionTitle}}</h1>

    <h2 class="bold">
      {{ description}}
    </h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    bSectionTitle: {
      type: [String]
    },
    description: {
      type: [String]
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

can someone help me to solve this and explain where I'm wrong in here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
<h1>{{ bSectionTitle}}</h1>
```

by this:

```
<h1 v-html="bSectionTitle"></h1>
```

In the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) they say:

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive

But note that:

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

If you need to render user-provided content use [any html sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=html+sanitizer) before passing the content to `v-html`

Comment: wow thankyou it works, but is there any drawbacks when using `v-html` ?

Comment: Yes. In the documentation: "Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content." So, if you want to render unknown content you need to use html sanitizer.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about something, can I ask again just to make sure? Is there any roundabout way to do this without using `v-html`?

Comment: `v-html` is the simplest vue native way. Other ways would be not so legal. What do you not like in `v-html`?

Comment: in fact I like it, since it easier to use, I just quite nervous about `XSS Vulnerabilities` but since I only use `v-html` for text I can conclude that it still safe right? as long as I'm not use it in `input` tag?

Comment: Yes, it's safe for the content you trust. In other cases, e.g. when you try to render html that comes from text-input, you need to [sanitize html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) before passing it to `v-html`